# Use Grails in Windows

Tags: grails

I need to use Grails for a project, I have the 2.2 version, JDK7.

I made my JAVA_HOME and my GRAILS_HOME variables, but when y try to run grails in my command, I have this answer :

> /grails-2.2.0/lib/org.springsource.springloaded/srpingloaded-core/jars/springloaded-core-1.1.1.jar
>   was unexpected

Can someone explain it to me please, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to install Grails into a directory without spaces in the path.
View [this](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7836) discussion.

Comment: Thanks for this link. Now it run! I just copy the Grails directory C:/ . Thanks for answer and have a happy day!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the GVM project: [www.gvmtool.net](http://www.gvmtool.net) With that and [www.cygwin.org](http://www.cygwin.org) you got a winning combination